# Typo3 cURL "SSL certificate not found" despite http verify set to "false"

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, typo3, self-signed, verifyerror

Error when trying to upgrade Typo3 or update an Extension via Backend (Server name obfuscated):

in `typo3_src-10.4.26/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php` line 449

```
        if (!file_exists($cert)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                "SSL certificate not found: {$cert}"
            );
        }
```

Configuration setting is:
`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['HTTP']['verify'] = false;`

Beside setting via BE (LocalConfiguration.php) also tried additionally with entry in AdditionalConfiguration.php

Normally it should not verify the SSL certificate with this setting as far as I understood it. Is there something else I can do to debug or solve this error?

Environment Info:

- Typo3 10.4.26
- PHP Version 7.4.30
- cURL 7.64.0
- Certificate self signed certbot certificate
- Server: HostEurope WebServer Basic with Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster),
  domain is the default HE server domain e.g. "wp12345678.server-he.de"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['HTTP']['cert'], and also provide the certificate in PEM format.

[image]

The link in the screenshot:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#cert

One reason that your setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['HTTP']['verify']` is not taken into account is that you have to clear the cache before the update perhaps.

Beside that, if the problem is only remarkable when you try to upgrade, you could do the upgrade manually.

Comment: Thx! For Host Europe WebServer the following pathes have to be set:
[HTTP][cert] = /etc/ssl/certs and 
[HTTP][ssl_key] = /etc/ssl/private.
Unfortunately now the error "Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz" is thrown for what the curl.cainfo has to be set in php.ini that I have no permissions for on the HE WebServer. Setting them via .htaccess in my webdirectory does not change the directives in php info:
php_value curl.cainfo "https://wp12345678.server-he.de/ssl/cacert.pem"
php_value openssl.cafile "https://wp12345677.server-he.de/ssl/cacert.pem"

Comment: the path for curl.cainfo must be a local path, no url

Comment: tried local and absolute, not allowed with this Webserver. Support said should use "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().'/is/htdocs/wp12345678_XXX/pfad/zum/cert.pem')"; How to do with Typo3 10.4.26 without having this option in $GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP]?

Comment: Where is the problem to place the certificate in the requested path?

Comment: no write permissions in /etc/ssl/certs, can only uload certificate and key via Server administration GUI, with what I uploaded cert.pem and privkey.pem

Comment: Your should be able to place an own php.ini in your home-directory or a subfolder. You might be able to see the correct directory by phpinfo()

Comment: unfortunately not possible with the managed WebServer, no effect

Comment: It's quite possible that they limit the options in favor of their paid services: https://www.hosteurope.de/SSL-Zertifikate/. Anyway, without having an account at HE by myself and without access to Host related documentation you should ask the support, perhaps there is some option and setting that can help you to reach the target.

Comment: I only see four inconvenient options, either fiddling with core classes to send curl option (an option to configure curl option cainfo would be nice in typo3) or using bought instead of self signed certificate or changing hoster or product. Thx anyway for all the hints!!

Comment: I would have given up on this perhaps and installed the new version manually